# creating network between 2 emulators running on 2 different pc's

Tags: android, android-emulator

we are doing an android chat application in 2.3.3 as a project in final year BE and very new to android, we thought of doing both anonymous and friends chatting together and wanted to show chatting in 2 different emulator running on two separate laptops. Is it possible to do so. We are stuck here from many days. Not getting any clear information how to achieve it.We are not getting how to create a network between 2 emulators running on two systems and do chatting, Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use indeed a server to communicate to as a middle-man. Not a direct connection between the two emulators.

Comment: we thought of doing the same.Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I have to start working on something similar :) Sure it is possible to communicate, it is necessary to use Android connected to App Engine, using the XMPP protocol.

[App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine)

[XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)

I think Google has some XMPP servers, so you can make use of them. I'm sorry not to help you more, but I just did the research, no coding yet!

Comment: since we are very new to android any hint or sample of this code or even link will be really appreciable